# Delphi: parse Python list into delphi struct

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I parse such python-like output (it's Python list of dicts) using Delphi 7 code?

```
[
{"CompletionText":"abstract","Description":"abstract-a","DisplayText":"abstract-aa"},
{"CompletionText":"class","Description":"class-b","DisplayText":"class-bb"},
{"CompletionText":"delegate","Description":"delegate-c","DisplayText":"delegate-cc"},
{"CompletionText":"using","Description":"using-cc","DisplayText":"using-dd"}
]
```

I need some Delphi scruct, to get "Description" value of n-th line, or "DisplayText" value of n-th line. n can be up to 1000.

Comment: How exactly was it generated by the Python code? Is it JSON or YAML?

Comment: It's output of OmniSharp C# server. Any example code, how to parse?

Comment: This looks like JSON.  Get (or simply write!) a JSON parser.  For example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/

Comment: @Alextp Generally, before you attempt to parse something, you need to know what it is. So, what is it? Is it JSON? Is it YAML? Or is it something else? You'll want to know the format before you attempt to parse it. And in fact what you have in the question is valid JSON, and valid YAML.

Comment: I see it's JSON, list of fixed 3 keys items.

Comment: You sure? That's valid YAML too don't you know. I think JSON is more likely, but you'll want to consult the documentation of whatever produces it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you do:

1. Read the documentation of whatever generates this file to find out what format it is. It might be JSON. It might be YAML. The documentation will specify which it is.
2. Let's assume, for sake of argument, that the file is JSON. The next step is to find a JSON parser. Modern Delphi comes with a built-in JSON parser. You have an older Delphi so you'll probably need a third party JSON parser.
3. Use the parser to read in the file.

Comment: Which JSON(i try it first, coz items are simple strings, in quotes) parser is simple and fast? Low footprint, Delphi 7.

Comment: That question (which library to use) is considered off topic here, FWIW. SuperObject is a good choice for JSON parser. And really, don't just guess at what the format is. Find out for sure.